# Email-ext Jenkins: How to send email with Tests statistics like Run: 10, Failed:2, Passed: 8

Tags: maven, jenkins, testng, email-ext

I use Maven+TestNG auto-tests run by Jenkins. I know that the is a token for failed tests like ${FAILED_TESTS} but it also includes long stack-trace which is difficult to read.

So I want Jenkins to send email like this: Run: 10, Failed:2, Passed: 8

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you could customize the email template by using the [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) and Jelly templates.

See http://softwaretestautomationnotes.blogspot.com/2011/07/customizing-post-build-email.html for an example of this.

I don't know of any way to do this out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
Run: ${TEST_COUNTS}, Failed: ${TEST_COUNTS,var="fail"}, Passed: {$TEST_COUNTS,var="pass"}
```

You can also print out the skipped tests -

```
Skipped: ${TEST_COUNTS,var="skip"}
```

Take a look at the source code for [TestCountsContent.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/emailext/plugins/content/TestCountsContent.java)

Or are you saying this doesn't work with TestNG?

Answer (score 1):

```
Total:${TEST_COUNTS, var="total"} 
Success:${TEST_COUNTS, var="pass"} 
Fail:${TEST_COUNTS, var="fail"}
```